# How to increase video encoding speed in ffmpeg?

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg

I am recording video clips and then joining all the clips in a final video.
Everything goes fine but the joining process takes too long.

Tried to using some ffmpeg filters from here:
https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264

And here is my ffmpeg command that I am using to increase the speed (which seems to be wrong):

```
command = new String[]{"-y",
                "-f",
                "concat",
                "-safe",
                "0",
                "-i",
                "/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/my_file.txt",
                "-c:v",
                "-preset",
                "fast",
                "-crf",
                "22",
                "copy",
                "-flags",
                "+global_header",
                "/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/SampleApp/" + videoOutputPath
        };
```

Please help! Thanks much.

Comment: Show the complete log output from the `ffmpeg` command. Many Android users are using an improperly configured x264 which results in significant slowness. The output will show if this is the case for you as well.

Answer (score 2):

Got the solution:

I missed some options as I am a newbie with ffmpeg:

Final command:

```
command = new String[]{"-y",
                "-f",
                "concat",
                "-safe",
                "0",
                "-i",
                "/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/my_file.txt",
                "-c:v",
                "libx264",
                "-preset",
                "ultrafast",
                "-crf",
                "28",
                "-c:a",
                "copy",
                "-flags",
                "+global_header",
                "/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/SampleApp/" + videoOutputPath
        };
```

Where "-preset ultrafast is one option to increase the encoding speed, along with CRF 28".

Comment: Thanks going to to test it out for copying video. What does CRF do? Does increasing 28 make a difference?

Comment: CRF stands for Constant Rate Factor in FFMPEG, it is an option you should use if you want to keep the best quality for your video and don't care about the file size. Quality varies from range of 0 to 51 where 0 is best (lossless) and 50 is worst possible. Default is 23 and sane range is 23 to 28. For more info: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264